# Disabling zoom in double click in ESRI map

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am using ESRI map version 4.1 for generating map in my angular application and its working fine. What I want now is to disable zoom on double click on the map. I have done lot of googling and most of them suggestion `stopPropagation()` method, but the `event` itself is not having this function and its throwing error.

what I have tried is

```
view.on('double-click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```

It is giving me the error

> event.stopPropagation is not a function

I am using ESRI javascript library version 4.1.

Anybody has any idea how can I stop zooming on double click?

Comment: https://codepen.io/mcantonbul/pen/YzKVRQJ It's working. Can u create example app? or
I think you could try changing the name of the "event" variable.

Comment: I am Using version 4.1. I have tried this link with 4.1 instead of 4.12, but its now zooming  on double click:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esri 4.1 did not provide this feature in the library. You must either upgrade or intervene. In this way, you can intervene and control the "double-click" event with your own method.

https://codepen.io/mcantonbul/pen/YzKVRQJ

```
require(["esri/Map", "esri/views/MapView"], function(Map, MapView) {
  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "streets"
  });

  var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    zoom: 4,
    center: [15, 65] // longitude, latitude
  });
  var myCustomDoubleClick = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
  };
  view.gestureManager.handlers.last["double-click"] = myCustomDoubleClick;
});
```

Comment: stopPropagation disables everything for that event. Is there a way to only disable zoom?

Answer (score 0):

try something like ,

```
$( "#target" ).dblclick(function(event) {
 event.stopPropagation()
});
```

Comment: Which element you meant by id 'target'? Double click is on the view itself, and its svg created by esri library

Comment: in your case "target" should be "view"

Comment: As you probably know, these are the selectors. I hope, when you are trying to bind an "double-click" event to the "view" element than that element id is "view".

Comment: Thank you Akash for your response, but I guess you misunderstood the concept. This view is an svg element created by ESRI library as a view.  Unlike normal svg, ESRI will create its own event handlers on 'view'. 'view' is not the id, it is the reference on which many functions are bound by library. FYI, here I am talking about ESRI Map view, not about DOM element. See this link : https://codepen.io/mcantonbul/pen/YzKVRQJ , you will get an idea

Comment: I see your point after looking at that codepen. yes, I misunderstood it and was thinking in terms of DOM only.